# How to use dependencies with yield in FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi, yield-return

I am using FastApi and I would like to know if I am using the dependencies correctly.

First, I have a function that yields the database session.

```
class ContextManager:
     def __init__(self):
         self.db = DBSession()
  
     def __enter__(self):
         return self.db

     def __exit__(self):
         self.db.close()

def get_db():
         with ContextManager() as db:
          yield db
```

I would like to use that function in another function:

```
def validate(db=Depends(get_db)):

  is_valid = verify(db)
  
  if not is is_valid:
     raise HTTPException(status_code=400)

  yield db
```

Finally, I would like to use the last functions as a dependency on the routes:

```
@router.get('/')
def get_data(db=Depends(validate)):

  data = db.query(...)

  return data
```

I am using this code and it seems to work, but I would like to know if it is the most appropiate way to use dependencies. Especially, I am not sure if I have to use 'yield db' inside the function validate or it would be better to use return. I would appreciate your help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Using `yield` is really only necessary if you want to do something _after_ you've yielded. In the case for `validate` that isn't happening, so there shouldn't be any need for using `yield` here. If your database always needs to pass your `is_valid` check, I'd also move that straight into `get_db` instead - or if you need both, use `get_valid_db` as the name instead of `validate` (what you're getting instead of what you're doing).

Comment: I understand what you say, but I do use the db after the yield. I use it in the route, if I don´t yield it in the validate function I can´t use it in the route

Comment: My point is that you can just use `return`, no need to use `yield` (which was your question).